# How do I query in Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm beating my head against a wall trying to query Mongo successfully.

This code:

```
    async.waterfall([
        function(callback){
            cursor = db.collection(collection).findOne(query)
            callback(null);
        },
        function(callback){
            console.log("Result is:" + cursor);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(cursor));
            callback(null);
        }
    ]);
```

Produces the following output:

```
result is:[object Object]
{}
```

Why? There is a document that it should be finding in the collection.

As a followup question, how do I get to see what

```
[object Object]
```

is?

Comment: Try  `"Result is:", cursor` instead of concatenating to log properly. You should pass the result of the query to the callback rather than the cursor. i.e. use the `callback` in the callback to `.findOne`. Is this the native MongoDB driver? What version?

Comment: I'm using Mongo v 3.0. Please can you explain / say this in different words: "You should pass the result of the query to the callback rather than the cursor. i.e. use the callback in the callback to .findOne". Thanks!     (Aside: the "Result is:", cursor change just prints {}.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you should wait for your query to complete and then call the callback and expect any result:

```
        async.waterfall([
            function(callback){
                db.collection(collection).findOne(query, function(err, result) {
                  callback(err, result); // if there is no err, it will be null
                });
                // the above can be simplified to just                                    
                // db.collection(collection).findOne(query, callback);
                // since findOne callback and current function callback have the same arguments
            },
            function(result, callback) {
                // use comma here to automatically doing JSON.stringiry(result)
                console.log("Result is:", result);
                callback();
            }
        ], function(err) {
           // here is your final callback where you know that async.waterfall 
           // is finished (with or without error)
        });
```